# ORA-00928 missing SELECT keyword in oracle doing a UPDATE

Tags: oracle, update

I'm doing an update in Oracle 11g but I have this error: ORA-00928.

This is my statement

```
UNION UPDATE EDU_ESTUDIANTES_NOTAS SET (ESN_VALOR_NOTA) VALUES (5) 
WHERE  ESN_ID=1093228292 AND ESN_ID_MAT_GRUPO=ID211743
```

Comment: What's that `UNION` supposed to mean? Consider looking up the correct syntax for `UPDATE` in the manual.

Comment: SQL statements never start with union, let alone update statements...

Answer (score 2):

Proper `UPDATE` [syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php) is:

```
 UPDATE table
   SET column1 = expression1,
       column2 = expression2,
       ...
       column_n = expression_n
  [WHERE conditions];
```

So, you should try this:

```
 UPDATE EDU_ESTUDIANTES_NOTAS 
    SET ESN_VALOR_NOTA = 5
  WHERE ESN_ID=1093228292 
    AND ESN_ID_MAT_GRUPO=ID211743 ;
```